# What was wrong with my translation?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-japanese

I'm trying to practice simple translation from English to Japanese.

I'm around N4 level so I started with something I thought was doable for me:

> Today I woke up at 9:00 am. After I got up, I walked Nacho outside so he could poo.

And this was the translation I did:

> 今日は９時午前に私が起きた。その後、外でナチョと散歩したからうんちする事ができる。

I thought I did it right, but when I checked on Google Translate, this is what came up:

> I woke up at 9am today. After that, I took a walk with Nacho outside
>   so **I can poop.**

---

What did I do wrong there?

I know Google Translate isn’t super reliable. So I want to check here if I really did miss something in my translation.

Can anyone shed some light? Thanks. :)

Comment: You should be careful with difference between 'so' meaning 'as a consequence of' and 'so' meaning 'in order to/that'. They are not the same word in Japanese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your translation.

> 今日は９時午前に私が起きた。その後、外でナチョと散歩したからうんちする事ができる。

I find nothing wrong with the first sentence. It may not be the most natural way of saying "I woke up 9 AM." but it does the job. The second sentence, however, needs some fixing. I see your attempt at translating "so" but as user3856370 mentioned, this translates to a different grammar [pattern](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB-you-ni/) which is not taught until around N3 level but is very useful.

If I were to translate the second sentence, I would write it something like this.

> その後、ナチョがうんこできるように、外に連れて行った。

Not the best translation, but I think it gets the message across.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I still get a little confused about when to use から since it can be used in a few different ways. After some googling, it looks like making use of ように makes more sense in this context. I appreciate your answer! Thank you.